# Shared Preferences for WIndows apps

Tags: sharedpreferences, windows-8.1, cross-application

Is it possible for windows app to have shared preferences like in android?

I plan to create two apps, one app would be the input app, while the second app
would read the input app and become the output app.

I was planning to use one app and use dual display. 
one display for input the other display for output,
but I found out this wasn't possible.

Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking, and don't see the connection to SharedPreferences. Maybe you could clarify the question.

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12759675/2683275) for shared preferences in windows

Comment: I want to create two applications running on the same device (windows rt). One application would be the app for inputting strings (example is string "235"). The second application would be the output for the first application. (showing "235"). How would I get the two application to communicate with each other? Sorry, i thought this was called shared preferenes, i guess not.